# sorting pattern algorithms in python

Tags: python

What i am trying to do is to prompt the user for an sort function type, sort patter, array size, size of array increment and number of test. Then i want it to save it. However, there are couple problems with this program.

1. Somehow when i choose the random pattern it gives me some weird answer like:

   1543    0.002

   600     0.020

   1400    0.08

Its not really in an order. I think that something wrong is with the for loop.

```
def rand_array(n):
''' returns sorted array of integers of size n'''
    R=[randint(1, 1000*n) for i in xrange(n)]
    return R

def sorted_array(n):
    ''' returns a sorted array of n integers'''
    return [i for i in xrange(1,n+1)]

def rev_array(n):
    '''returns an array of n integers in reverse order'''
    R= [i for i in reversed(xrange(1,n+1))]
    return R

 def sort_timehelp(x,f):
    ''' This times the quick sort algorithm as it must take 3 variables'''
    high=len(x)
    low=0
    t0=clock()
    f(x,low,high)
    t1=clock()
    dt=t1-t0
    return dt

def main():
    myinfo()
    info()
    while True:
        print '==================== to quit enter Control-c=================='
        sortfunction=input("Choose a sort function: ")
        s=input("Choose a pattern: ")
        n=input("Array Size: ")
        increment=input("Increment size: ")
        y=input("Number of tests: ")

        if s == 1:
            x=rand_array(n)
        elif s ==2:
            x= sorted_array(n)
        elif s==3:
            x=rev_array(n)
        if sortfunction==1:
            i=0
            output="algorith: quick sort \n input data: %s" %s
            print output
            while i<y:
                i=i+1
                ff=0.0
                array=x[increment-1:n:increment]
                for my in array:
                    ff+=sort_timehelp(x,quick_sort)
                    output="%d\t %f" %(my, ff)
                    print output

          saving=input("You want to save data ? type 0 to continue or 1 to save " )

          if saving == 0:
              continue
          if saving == 1:
              ask=raw_input("Type the name file: ")
              fileout=open(ask+".csv","w")
              fileout.write(output)
              fileout.close()
```

Second problem is that when i am trying to save the data it only saves the last data, but i want to save everything.

I would appreciate any help.

Edit:
timing function takes and array and a sorting algorithm
i want to save the numbers by increments and corresponding timing to it. (thats where my for loop)

Comment: A few comments: **1)** Why are you passing two arguments to your sort function `sortfun(x,n)`? **2)** Your doc strings don't actually describe your functions. **3)** When you say you want to save everything, do you mean within each branch of `while True` or each instance of the variable `output`?

Comment: the lines after 'output="%d\t %f" %(my, ff)
                    print output' are not properly indented.

Comment: indentations are correct

Comment: Additionally, why is the output you describe weird? We have no way of knowing what's weird or not, especially since this code doesn't run as posted.

Comment: @M W, when you claim that indentations are correct when they are clearly not, you lose credibility.

Comment: saving=input(You want to sa.....) line is not indented properly.

Comment: this is just portion of my coding, and i have lot more for loops so thats why my saving is last and in the while loop. so the indentation is correct

Comment: Next time, put a `# ...` comment in places where you omit lines like that.

Comment: I'll simply reiterate. The code doesn't run as posted, because the indentation, as posted, is incorrect. When you have a question, you should paste a [short, self-contained, correct, example](http://sscce.org/). Your example is not [correct](http://sscce.org/#co).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues. Let's go through them...

```
def rand_array(n):
''' returns sorted array of integers of size n'''
    R=[randint(1, 1000*n) for i in xrange(n)]
    return R
```

This doesn't return a sorted array of random numbers. It returns a list of random integers chosen from successively larger domains. You probably want:

```
def rand_array(n):
''' returns sorted array of integers of size n'''
    return sorted([randint(1, 1000) for i in xrange(n)])
```

---

```
def sorted_array(n):
    ''' returns a sorted array of n integers'''
    return [i for i in xrange(1,n+1)]
```

This should simply be:

```
def sorted_array(n):
    ''' returns a sorted array of n integers'''
    return range(1, n + 1)
```

---

```
def rev_array(n):
    '''returns an array of n integers in reverse order'''
    R= [i for i in reversed(xrange(1,n+1))]
    return R
```

is simply:

```
def rev_array(n):
    '''returns an array of n integers in reverse order'''
    return reversed(sorted_array(n))
```

---

```
            i=0
            output="algorith: quick sort \n input data: %s" %s
            print output
            while i<y:
                i=i+1
                ff=0.0
                array=x[increment-1:n:increment]
                for my in array:
                    ff+=sort_timehelp(x,quick_sort)
                    output="%d\t %f" %(my, ff)
                    print output
```

So you're sorting as many times (in the inner loop) as you have array elements? Not sure why. Anyway, the business with `i` should simply be done with a `for` loop:

```
            print "algorith: quick sort \n input data: %s" %s
            for i in range(y):
                ff = 0.0
                array = x[increment-1:n:increment]
                for my in array:
                    ff += sort_timehelp(x, quick_sort)
                    output = "%d\t %f" %(my, ff)
                    print output
```

---

```
          saving=input("You want to save data ? type 0 to continue or 1 to save " )

          if saving == 0:
              continue
          if saving == 1:
              ask=raw_input("Type the name file: ")
              fileout=open(ask+".csv","w")
              fileout.write(output)
              fileout.close()
```

The `if saving==0` clause can be removed; any value of `saving` other than `1` will skip saving.

As Scott pointed out, you want `"a"` instead of `"w"` in `open`. Another thing you could do is move the `open` and `close` out of the loop. You might also want to use the built-in Python `csv` module.

Answer (score 3):

Your random pattern is actually a random pattern, not a sorted list as the docstring suggests.

To save everything, open your output file for appending, not just writing (which, as you've found, overwrites the previous contents).  That is, use "a" instead of "w".